Create output directory in the same place as input file in python
I have a script like this and use it by drag and drop video files into it for processing with ffmpeg. But now I want to create an output folder in the same place as the input file, what should I do?.
import os
from pathlib import Path

CWD = os.getcwd()
dirPath = CWD.replace("\\", "/")
ffmpeg = f"{dirPath}/ffmpeg.exe"
outPath = f"{dirPath}/Output"

inputFile = input("Input File (provide full path):")
name = Path(inputFile).stem  # Get the file name without extension
os.system(f"{ffmpeg} -y -hide_banner -v quiet -stats -i {inputFile} -vf fps=1/300 -vframes 12 {outPath}/{name}%03d.png")

I tried many times but it didn't work. I never learned about python but just researched it on the internet

Do you know the input path? and what device are you using?

I use windows 10. And my input is a video file located anywhere on the computer, I open the .py file then drag and drop the video file there.
Sorry for my bad English!

Do you know the input path?

If you're getting the input path as an argument, use os.dirname() to get the directory portion. You can then use os.path.join() to combine that with the output folder name.
